# Find components of external java applications and use them

Tags: java, swing, automation, external, jtextfield

My problem looks like:
I have an external application written in java which I start. 
Next is to start my application. It should find the JTextFields of external application and set proper text values for them. At the end, fires the JButton which is placed somewhere on this window.

I have already tried the solution [Java search for on-screen text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771637/java-search-for-on-screen-text-field), but somehow it cannot find the specific sub-windows

the output generated by this solution is:

```
...
Window found: EnumWindows - NetBeans IDE 7.3 Beta 2
Window found: ToolkitEventListener2
Window found: theAwtToolkitWindow
Window found: 
...
```

The title of JFrame is ToolkitEventListener2 and it creates JMenu and JButton.

I hope I explained the problem well and you will be able to help me.

Answer (score 3):

`java.awt.Window` class has a static method

```
public static Window[] getWindows()
```

Use this to get list of all existing windows. Find proper `JFrame` (or `JDialog`) by title or by focus and get all the child components (recoursively). Filter out all `JTextFields` and use their values.

Comment: hmm ... that would get all the (owned or not) windows of the application it's called from, not from _external_ applications.

Comment: @kleopatra  But since *"external application written in java which I start"*, that might be moved into *"my application*" and started, not using a `ProcessBuilder`, since that would also create a separate JVM, but simply either construct an instance of the other app. or call the `main(String)`?  Done that way, the `Window` instances *would* be available.