# Manipulate program with java

Tags: java, swing, field, bittorrent, utorrent

I don't know if this is possible (I searched a lot on google), but I want to manipulate the fields of a running program (utorrent). After I open a file (let's say example.torrent), utorrent pops up and asks for a folder to save the files to. What I want to do is to complete that field with a certain path that i give dinamically with my java program and press OK, and all of this should happen in the background (I don't want to see how the file is opened).

Comment: you may find an answer i have written in the past helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771637/java-search-for-on-screen-text-field/11773426#11773426

Comment: The answer to your question I think is going to be no, its not possible. I'm not real familiar with the Robot class in java and I'm not sure what it can do other than move the cursor but that would be my best guess if something like this were possible. You would have to find the text field then insert a String. You might be better of using C# or Mono, the framework is different but the syntax is very similar to Java and its much better for native integration, which I would assume is required to find the text field on the screen. Sorry I don't really have an answer, good luck.

Comment: well... C# code is fine also, I went with java because I thought it has more reach than C# or C++, but as I said C# is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. It can control the mouse position, caret position, key presses ect. Although it is designed for demo purposes I'm sure you could modify it to your needs.