# jna send edit control messages

Tags: java, jna

apologies in advance as I'm a novice.

I'm trying to work with a windows based game called rFactor with java and the JNA library. I have seen what I want to do by people using c++.

So far I have this (I copied the bulk of it from another stackoverflow post [Java search for on-screen text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771637/java-search-for-on-screen-text-field)):

```
package au.gov.nsw.lpi.bds.jnatest;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.examples.win32.W32API.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.examples.win32.W32API.LPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

public class IterateChildWindows {
public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    int SendMessage(HWND hWnd, int msg, int wParam, byte[] lParam);

    boolean FindWindowEx(HWND parent, HWND child, String className, String window);

    boolean EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer arg);

    boolean EnumChildWindows(HWND parent, WNDENUMPROC callback, LPARAM info);

    interface WNDENUMPROC extends StdCallCallback {
        boolean callback(HWND name, Pointer arg);
    }

    int GetWindowTextA(HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);

    int GetClassNameA(HWND in, byte[] lpString, int size);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    User32.INSTANCE.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {
        public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer userData) {
            byte[] textBuffer = new byte[512];
            User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, textBuffer, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(textBuffer);

            if (wText.contains("ISI Dedicated Server")) {

                if (User32.INSTANCE.FindWindowEx(hWnd, null, "Static", "Game Name:")) {
                    System.out.println(new String(textBuffer).trim() + " - " + hWnd);

                    User32.INSTANCE.EnumChildWindows(hWnd, new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {
                        int count = 1;

                        public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer userData) {
                            byte[] textBuffer = new byte[512];
                            User32.INSTANCE.GetClassNameA(hWnd, textBuffer, 512);

                            if ((new String(textBuffer).trim()).contains("Edit")) {
                                System.out.println(new String(textBuffer).trim());
                                System.out.println(hWnd);

                                // User32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(hWnd,
                                // WM_SETTEXT, msg.length(), (LPARAM) msg);
                            }

                            if ((new String(textBuffer).trim()).contains("Button")) {
                                if (count == 8) {
                                    System.out.println(new String(textBuffer).trim() + " " + count);
                                    System.out.println(hWnd);
                                }
                                count++;
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    }, null);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }, null);
}
}
```

This produces

```
ISI Dedicated Server - native@0x207e0 (com.sun.jna.examples.win32.W32API$HWND@207e0)
Edit
native@0x207ac (com.sun.jna.examples.win32.W32API$HWND@207ac)
Button 8
native@0x207a8 (com.sun.jna.examples.win32.W32API$HWND@207a8)
```

I think I'm on the right track as I've isolated the right "EDIT" and "BUTTON" that I need. I believe I now need to put text into the edit field and then use the button using

```
int SendMessage(HWND hWnd, int msg, int wParam, byte[] lParam);
```

This is an example from c++

```
SendMessage(chatHwnd, WM_SETTEXT, msgSB.Length, msgSB)
```

I've tried but had no luck getting it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit, I've tried this (though I'm pretty much fumbling in the dark)

```
int SendMessage(HWND hWnd, int msg, int wParam, byte[] lParam);
```

and this

```
public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer userData) {
    byte[] textBuffer = new byte[512];
User32.INSTANCE.GetClassNameA(hWnd, textBuffer, 512);
    if ((new String(textBuffer).trim()).contains("Edit")) {
    User32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(hWnd,0xC, msg.length, 
            Native.toByteArray("MessageFromNick"));
                            }

if ((new String(textBuffer).trim()).contains("Button")) {
    if (count == 8) {
    User32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0201, 0, 0);
}

count++;
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly didn't work?  You'll need to use [`Native.toByteArray(String)`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#toByteArray(java.lang.String)) to obtain a properly null-terminated array of bytes (or array of `char` if you're using the unicode version of `SendMessage`).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I edited the original post to contain the things I have tried. Regards, Nick

Comment: I got it to work with this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageA(hWnd, 0x000C, 0, Native.toByteArray("TextMessage"));

0x000C refers to WM_SETTEXT

Comment: Please provide the correct interface declaration and mark this as the answer @user2738572

Answer (score 0):

Interface:

```
static Map UNICODE_OPTIONS = new HashMap() {
    {
        put("type-mapper", com.sun.jna.win32.W32APITypeMapper.UNICODE);
        put("function-mapper", com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIFunctionMapper.UNICODE);
    }
};

public interface UUser32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    UUser32 INSTANCE = (UUser32)(UUser32)Native.load("user32", UUser32.class, UNICODE_OPTIONS);

    int SendMessage(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND hWnd, int msg, int wParam, char[] lParam);
}
```

Call:

```
static final int WM_SETTEX = 0x000C;//from winuser.h
static public void setEditText(com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND windowH, com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND editH, String text){
    user32.SetForegroundWindow(windowH);//user32 is User32.INSTANCE defined in com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
    char[] ctext = Native.toCharArray(text);
    UUser32.INSTANCE.SendMessage(editH, WM_SETTEX, 0, ctext);
}
```